# Assembly.Load + Dependencies

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am facing an issue when loading DLLs and their references. The scenario is this:

I have a C# library project (let's call it "A") which references another C# library project (let's call it "B"). Both the Dlls of these projects are stored on Azure Blob storage but this is irrelevant in reality.

As part of my project I am using `XslCompiledTransform.Transform`. After loading dll A using `Assembly.Load`, I then load dll B using again `Assembly.Load`.

The issue is that after executing the `Transform` method I keep getting an error that **dll B cannot be found**, even though it is present when I call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();`

As a note, if I remove the dependency of B from A everything works, so we can ensure that the `Transform`, using just dll A, is working.

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xxx,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

One more thing, if I add dll B to the projects Bin folder then it works, but of course, I cannot do this, I just did this to prove that it works.

Comment: Are you sure the exception isn't happening in another application domain? Have you considered handling the assembly load in the app domain's `AssemblyResolve` event instead?

Comment: Dlls have to be loaded on the fly. I do not want go into to much detail how the system needs to work as I have very little control when it comes to the design. Not sure about your first comment, but as stated in the end if I include dll B in the bin of the project which is loading A and B everything works as expected. But this is something I cannot do since the dlls are random.

Comment: How "random"? There's many limitations when working with dynamic loading. For example, you can't have two assemblies with the same name and a different version in the same domain. `XslCompiledTransform` also deals with dynamically created/loaded libraries, so there might be all sorts of version collisions, or it might be using a different `AppDomain` to execute the transformation (pure speculation). None of your comment really addresses what I said in my comment either :)

Comment: Yes I understand most of the limitations. Honestly, I have to do more research about how domains work because that might be the issue. Regarding the AssemblyResolve event, that too I need to research.

Comment: @Luaan, quick question. Do you know a way around this or maybe have some guides/tutorials which can clarify more the issue I am facing?

Comment: You can enable the FusionLog to get some idea of how the runtime is looking for the assembly, but it probably isn't going to be useful in this case. In general, anything weird you do to assembly resolution is going to be a bit of a pain - it's hard to debug, you need to have a good understanding of how the .NET runtime works and all that. All I can really recommend you is to be extra careful that the assemblies you're talking about are exactly the way they're supposed to be (e.g. from the same build etc.), and that there's no name/version conflict, ever. .NET will not load the same name twice.

Comment: @Luaan Understood, thanks for your help. I am sure it is only being added once and yes the build is the same. The part which confuses me is that if I add the "missing library" directly to the BIN of the running project everything works as expected.

Comment: I would try writing out some debug output in the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event at least - it will give you some idea of what assemblies are being loaded and when, and if it's actually trying (and failing) in your domain.

Comment: Hi Luaan thnx the issue has been solved! Yes that was the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @Luaan, I had to use AppDomain.AssemblyResolve and return the assembly that was being loaded.

[image]